# AlarmManager Doesn't work when app is closed

Tags: java, android

```
public class background_alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         //CODE EVERY X MINUTES
} }
```

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



AlarmManager alarmManager;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, background_alarm.class);
    intent.putExtra("UserNumber", UserLogged.getNumeroTelefono());

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Long intervalMillis = 1L * 60L * 1000L; //IT'S ONLY FOR TEST 1 MINUTES
    Long triggerAtMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalMillis;

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, pendingIntent);

}
```

When the app is closed this doesn't work anymore... There is a solution to run ever? NOTE: When app is running this work

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that your device is entering DOZE mode.
Use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() methods in your background alarm class https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Answer (score 0):

For this specific scenario I suggest you to use a foreground service.

From the documentation:

> Apps that have been running foreground services (with the associated notification) are not restricted by doze.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services